# CBOR serialization and deserialization on different platforms

Tags: qt, serialization, deserialization, cbor

I write a client-server application where the server is a Linux machine, and the client is a Windows machine. I serialize data using CBOR before sending them over a network.

I serialized data on the server and obtained `"\x83\x01\x00\xf4"`. However, when trying to deserialize it on Windows, I get `ASSERT: "recursed->type == CborInvalidType" in file C:\Users\qt\qtbase\src\3rdparty\tinycbor\src\cborparser.c, line 633` error. When I tested it in a Linux-to-Linux setup, it worked fine.

Here is a very simple application that demonstrates the error (runs or Linux, crashes on Windows):

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QCborStreamReader>
#include <QCborStreamWriter>

enum PacketType
{
    packet,
    sharedVar,
    sigcom
};

enum TypeName
{
    whatever
};

// this is how I serialize data on Linux
QByteArray serializeBOOL(bool t, TypeName typeName)
{
    QByteArray arr;
    QCborStreamWriter writer(&arr);

    writer.startArray(3);
    writer.append(PacketType::sharedVar);
    writer.append(typeName);
    writer.append(t);
    writer.endArray();

    return arr;
}

PacketType getPacketType(const QByteArray &arr)
{
    QCborStreamReader reader(arr);

    reader.enterContainer();
    PacketType type = static_cast<PacketType>(reader.toInteger());
    reader.leaveContainer();

    return type;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QByteArray arr = serializeBOOL(false, whatever);

    getPacketType(arr);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I thought CBOR could be used across platforms similarly to JSON. Is that not the case?

Comment: Since you only have four bytes and your code needs at least 8 (or even 12) because your integer is in an container I would guess your data is wrong.

Comment: @chehrlic I modified the example above with how I serialized the data on the Linux machine. What is the problem there?

Comment: I was wrong about the expected length - cbor 'compresses' the values by removing leading empty bytes. You forgot to go to the end of your array which is needed - add 3 times `reader.next()` to go to the end of the array

Comment: Thank you, @chehrlic; that was indeed the issue. I decided to ignore l`eaveContainer()` entirely because the length of my packets is arbitrary, meaning I would need an arbitrary number of `reader.next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you could not leave the container if you were not at the end.

The solution was adding 3x `reader.next()` into `PacketType getPacketType(const QByteArray &arr)`. Another option would be not to leave a container.

```
PacketType getPacketType(const QByteArray &arr)
{
    QCborStreamReader reader(arr);

    reader.enterContainer();
    PacketType type = static_cast<PacketType>(reader.toInteger());
    reader.next();
    reader.next();
    reader.next();
    reader.leaveContainer();

    return type;
}
```